# Plotting a ArcCos function

Tags: plotting

I didn't manage to plot a simple function with ArcCos.

```
Plot[ArcCos[(x + 1)/Sqrt[x]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

With this function, the plot returned is empty.

Do you have some ideas for conducting this plotting ?

Comment: For Power function I remember that to not have this problem I use Surd rather than Power.
Is there a equivalent for inverse trigonometric functions ?

Comment: May be a stupid question but I would like to be sure. If I put Re do I obtain the same plot that I could obtain a Ti calc for example ?

Answer (score 2):

The function is complex-valued, try

```
Plot[Re[ArcCos[(x + 1)/Sqrt[x]]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: Wouldn't be more instructive e.g. `Plot[{Re @ #, Im @ #}& @ ArcCos[(x + 1)/Sqrt[x]], {x, -1, 1},  Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick]`?

Comment: Or `Plot[ReIm@ArcCos[(x + 1)/Sqrt[x]], {x, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: I try this : Plot[Re[ArcCos[(x + 1)/Sqrt[x]]], {x, -2, 2}]
But my plot seems to be a bit strange ???

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the square root of a complex number is used here, we choose the root with the positive real part (or positive imaginary part if the square was negative real).

$\arccos x=2 \arctan \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x},   if -1<x\le 1 $

```
Plot[Im[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[-x^2 - x - 1]/Sqrt[x] + x + 1]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot of imaginary part]

The same for the real part:

```
 Plot[Re[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[-x^2 - x - 1]/Sqrt[x] + x + 1]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot of real part]